# Particle bouncing off spherical boundaries 3D

Tags: algorithm, 3d, bounce, particles

It's weird, but I couldn't find any clear algorithm for bouncing off spherical boundaries in 3D space.

For examples, I have a particle with an arbitrary velocity inside a hollow sphere. This particle doesn't have any shape/body, just a point coordinate.

[image: initial set]

It's more likely that have to find a plane when the particle hits the edges [distance from sphere origin is bigger than sphere radius) and calculate the reflection angle from that plane.

[image: plane]

However, maybe there is an alternative way?

Comment: nope, that's the right way, but the plane normal is just the vector from the particle to the center, so it's super easy.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment:

Let **P** be the particle position, **V** be the particle velocity, and let **C** be the center of the circle.

Then:

1. Calculate the tangent plane normal: **N = (C-P)/|C-P|**
2. Calculate the normal component of the velocity: **Vn = N·V**
3. Ensure it's pointed inward:  **if (Vn < 0) then V+=2*Vn*N**

You can rearrange to get rid of the square root:

1. **N = C-P**
2. **Vn = N·V**
3. **if (Vn<0) then V+=2*Vn*N/|N|²**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you mean by Vn < 0? Vn is 3D vector, so I have to check each coordinate [x,y,z] or its a coordinates sum?

Comment: **Vn** is a scalar -- the dot product of **N** and **V**

Comment: Look what I've got. Particle goes the opposite direction. In some ways, this work, but I need more realistic reflection.

Comment: Yes, if you start in the center you'll bounce right back to the center.  No matter where you start it'll stay in the same plane.  You'll need to cheat if you want an interesting pattern.

Comment: Your solution works, but if I need to keep speed/velocity, on deflection this parameter set to zero, so I've to build a prolonged trajectory to keep movement at right speed

Comment: PS: The devil in the details